# Disable JavaScript modules on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm looking for a flag to disable `<script type="module">` (import / export features) on Chrome for testing purpose.

On Firefox, there is "dom.moduleScripts.enabled" flag to toggle the feature.

Any idea ?

Edit:

- If you are interested in this feature, add +1 here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/VKDYWu5fmGM;context-place=forum/chrome
- Also here, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=814733

Comment: The Firefox flag is definitely not for testing, and it's going to go away very soon: It already is not 100% effective at emulating a browser pre-module script support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. If you look in `chrome://flags` and search on "module", there are two flags currently (v64.0.3282.167):

- Enable ECMAScript 6 modules dynamic import
- Enable ECMAScript 6 modules import.meta.url

Neither of them disables basic module support, but rather, advanced features currently still being specified.